# Getting next element in time series pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so, I want to create a new column `next_domain`.

It's calculated by looking for the next domain for an IP by the timestamp. It's N/A if the domain is the last domain for a certain IP. How can i do this in pandas?

**Input:**

```
    domain      ip      timestamp
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55
```

**Expected output:**

In the following table , row 2 has switch = 1 because it switches to Facebook right after (as seen in the timestamp) for the same IP.

Row 7 is a switch because Youtube changes to Google for IP 103, Row 8 is a switch because Google changes to Facebook for IP 103, and Row 10 is not a switch because there is no domain after Youtube.

```
    domain      ip      timestamp              next_domain
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33    N/A
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35    N/A
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41    Google
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46    Google
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01    Google
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13    Youtube
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55    N/A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the first domain of each stretch, `bfill` per group and `shift`:

```
s = df['domain']
df['next_domain'] = (s.where(s.ne(s.shift())) # keep only first domain of each stretch
                      .groupby(df['ip'])                    # per group
                      .apply(lambda s: s.bfill().shift(-1)) # bfill and shift up
                    )
```

output:

```
      domain   ip            timestamp next_domain
0     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook
1     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook
2     Google  101  2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook
3   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:33         NaN
4   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:35         NaN
5    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:01:41      Google
6    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:11:46      Google
7    Youtube  103  2020-04-22 01:01:01      Google
8     Google  103  2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook
9   Facebook  103  2020-04-23 14:11:13     Youtube
10   Youtube  103  2020-04-23 14:11:55         NaN
```

Comment: I like this solution. Would you be able to use same logic for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788353/getting-next-element-in-time-series-pandas?

Comment: @Elsen You probably meant to link another question ;)

Comment: Sorry! this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852633/getting-next-elements-by-time-with-shift-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @Eisen [here you are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70852874/16343464)

Comment: @mozway I'm following this chain of problems right now, I was wondering how you got the DataFrame from the original input. Is there a tool to change the text into the DataFrame instead of having to type out the whole thing?

Comment: @Richard you can copy the text and use `pd.read_clipboard()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.assign(col1=dd.domain.ne(dd.domain.shift()).cumsum())
    dd2=dd1.drop_duplicates(subset='col1',keep='last').sort_values('timestamp')
    dd3=dd2.assign(next_domain=dd2.domain.shift(-1))
    return dd1.join(dd3.set_index('col1')['next_domain'],on='col1').drop("col1",axis=1)

df1.groupby('ip').apply(function1)
```

output：

```
      domain   ip            timestamp next_domain
0     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook
1     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook
2     Google  101  2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook
3   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:33        None
4   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:35        None
5    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:01:41      Google
6    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:11:46      Google
7    Youtube  103  2020-04-22 01:01:01      Google
8     Google  103  2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook
9   Facebook  103  2020-04-23 14:11:13     Youtube
10   Youtube  103  2020-04-23 14:11:55        None
```